# Re-Assigning instance of AVAudioPlayer in iOS13 leads to BAD_ACCESS runtime error

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, exc-bad-access

I have an app, that is for many years in the AppStore and runs without any crashes (last deployment target iOS 12.4). I have some code for playing a sound on certain events in the app.

Now I tried to upgrade my app for iOS 13 and without changing any code related to that “playSound” thing, I always get this *runtime error*, when testing on a *real device*. Does not happen on *simulator*.

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)[image: Shows the error message]

**PLEASE**: Before you mark that question as *“duplicate”*, consider that this must have something to do with the release of iOS13, because before it didn’t happen and the code is just "usual".

Here is my code, also on [gitHub](https://github.com/RobertWoodapple/AVAudioPlayerWithBadAccessProblem).

I have a property in my ViewController to prevent ARC deallocating my AVAudioPlayer:

```
private var mySoundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

I have a routine, where the “play sound” should be performed (here happens the error, when *assigning* a new instance of AVAudioPlayer. The resourceURL is not the problem, the RE-ASSIGNING is the problem, I tested it with a new instance not being assigned and i did not crash.

```
// -------------------------------------------------
// MARK: Private Methods
// -------------------------------------------------

private func makeSoundEvent(_ soundEvent : SoundEvent) {
    
    guard Settings().getSound() == .soundON else { return }
    guard let urlToRessource : URL = soundEvent.getFileURLToSoundRessource() else { return }
    do {
        mySoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlToRessource)
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        mySoundPlayer.play()
    }
    catch { print("Could not create AVPlayer for ressource \(urlToRessource)") }
}
```

And here I have the call of that subroutine, somewhere in my viewDidLoad() with a delay of 2 seconds.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    self.makeSoundEvent(.startFanfare)
}
```

I think it somehow does not work because of the *async* thread. But since it is on the main thread, I thought this should work.

Comment: any reproduction project?

Comment: @J.Doe : I added a simple project for reproducing the error on gitHub (see link in my edited post). Thanks for beeng interested in my problem.

Comment: Why did you need before to use `= AVAudioPlayer()`? It's creating a player with no config, with no reason, no? Might be some change here on creating the private var and accessing them in IOS13?

Comment: @Larme: You are right, I didn't like it either, but you find lots of tutorials out there doing that exactly that way:
https://codewithchris.com/avaudioplayer-tutorial/
https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/play-music-avaudioplayer-ios-tutorial

Comment: And I think I found it also at Apples code samples (objective-c though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the initialisation and it will work

```
private var mySoundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Guess what: That really and unbelievable makes a different. My first test was fine. But WHY? Can you offer some explanation? Why is the assignment to an optional working, but not to an virgin AVAudioPlayer() and why it works after that, when other sound events created the same way and the property does really have already an instance of AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: There are 2 ways of doing this, either you do it like above 
`private var mySoundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!`

or 

`var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer! = nil`

The purpose is initialise the variable with nil. Hope that helps.

Comment: This does fix the crash problem for me, but the sounds doesnt work. Is this the case for you as well?

Comment: @nullforlife the sound plays for me

Comment: Why is this the case!?!?

Answer (score 3):

> `private var mySoundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()`

`AVAudioPlayer` doesn't have `init()` listed as a valid initializer. The [reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) shows four separate initializers, all of which take at least one parameter. If you were using the line above in code prior to iOS 13.1 without crashing, you were initializing the audio player incorrectly and probably just getting lucky that it wasn't a problem.

I don't know what changed specifically with `AVAudioPlayer` in iOS 13.1, but the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_1_release_notes) show quite a few audio-related changes, and it seems likely that some change to that class introduced a dependency on something that happens at initialization time.

Comment: Usually if you use an initializer that does not exist, the compiler complaints, but here it doesn't. To get a runtime error instead and not in the simulator but only on devices seems to me a bit a sloppy API from Apple.