# look at this and tell me what im missing

Tags: xcode

I have this code, that on button press it plays a sound. it works on the simulator, but when I send it to my device for testing, I get this error; EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48). I have the latest version of xcode and I believe its in swift 5???. any help would be greatly appreciate it. also note I don't have a paid developer account.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var musicEffect: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var muffin: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var muffin_text: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var muffin_button: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let musicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "muffin", ofType: ".mp3")
        do {
            try musicEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: musicFile!))
        }    
        catch {
            print(error)
        }                  
    }        

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {

       musicEffect.play() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace.

Comment: `var musicEffect: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` Change that line. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181247/psa-avaudioplayer-alloc-init-crashes-in-ios-13-1-and-avaudioplayer and there are two linked questions in SO (including Swift code)

Answer (score 1):

I'm brand new to Xcode and Swift but I would remove the (.)mp3. I believe the dot is implied without having to write it.

Comment: Hi That didnt work. i get this in the debug console. musicFile 

String? "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E5CE4ADD-5115-49C1-AD19-73249EE23790/Muffin Time.app/muffin.mp3"

Answer (score 0):

> it works on the simulator, but when I send it to my device for testing, I get this error

One big difference between iOS and macOS is that the filesystem on an iOS device is case-sensitive, whereas many (but not all) filesystems on macOS are case-insensitive. Whenever I see a question like "it works on the simulator but not on the device" I think *this is probably related to reading a file*.

So, check the capitalization of the file `muffin.mp3` in your app. Is it actually `Muffin.mp3` or `muffin.MP3` or `MUFFIN.mp3` or similar? If it's not exactly `muffin.mp3`, but instead has some capital letter, that would explain not finding the file. And your code doesn't check whether the value in `musicEffect` is valid before you try to play it, which explains why you might get an error.

---

**Update:** After looking at @Larme's comment, I think that incorrect initializer is more likely the problem if you're using iOS 13.1. See [Assigning instance of AVAudioPlayer in iOS13 leads to BAD_ACCESS runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58166133/643383) for example. `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't have a plain `init()` initializer, so you need to initialize it with some data, e.g.:

```
`var musicEffect: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: someAudioData)`
```

Comment: What do i put in there anything i put i get anUse of unresolved identifier error?

Comment: @TomFellas You can make `musicEffect` an implicitly unwrapped optional, like `var musicEffect: AVAudioPlayer!`, and then just make sure that you assign a value to it before you use it.