# Can't play local mp3 above ios13 swift

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, ios13

I have an app that play local mp3 files within the app that doesnt work in iOS 13 but lower os it works....

appending this in the array before:

Declare this in the class:

```
var MediaPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Sending in to the function in viewdidload:

```
TrackListData.append(Track(TrackName: "Introduction",TrackDescription: "About the good reasons for taking mindful breaks", TrackURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Introduction", ofType: "mp3")!)))
```

```
setSong(trackURL: TrackListArray[0].TrackList[0].TrackURL)
```

```
func setSong(trackURL : URL){
        do{
            MediaPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            MediaPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: trackURL)
            ProgressbarSong.maximumValue = Float(MediaPlayer.duration)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Get this error in the function setSong at line: MediaPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: trackURL)

Error:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x58)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-Assigning instance of AVAudioPlayer in iOS13 leads to BAD\_ACCESS runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166133/re-assigning-instance-of-avaudioplayer-in-ios13-leads-to-bad-access-runtime-erro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [58166133](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166133/re-assigning-instance-of-avaudioplayer-in-ios13-leads-to-bad-access-runtime-erro).

`AVAudioPlayer` doesn't have an init so you should update your first line, like this

```
var MediaPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```